# Center Body & Multiple Images?

Tags: html, css

I know it sounds really weird, but I'm trying to code a website with very little CSS knowledge. It's just a test website, so that I can get into the language a bit more, but I'm having some troubles. I can't find the answers anywhere. In case necessary, I've included the HTML and CSS files at the bottom.

**1. Center Body**

I was wondering how to center the body of my website? I know it seems simple, but I've looked on every single Google link and I can't find a solution. When I zoom in to test my website on 175% zoom increase, as that's what most monitors have at least, I notice that my browser is scrolling in to the left side of the website, rather than the center. I would like the elements of the website to be in the center, so that it doesn't end up with a blank space on the right like YouTube has for larger monitors. However, I have no idea on whether or not there is there a way I can make the website zoom to the center?

**2. Multiple Images**

When I was slicing the website layout I made, I took three images from one of the 'rounded rectangle' shapes. My aim is to make it so I can have the shape become expandable, meaning that it'll be a small box [ ] for small numbers, but if the number has more digits, the box can expand without breaking the website. Because of this, I sliced the LEFT and RIGHT side of the content box, as well as a 1px inside which I hoped to expand. I have no idea where to look for a tutorial, however, on how to make them all work together. If somebody could point me in the right direction, I'd be extremely grateful.

**3. Following**

Resolved - a huge thanks to Nicole Bieber who helped me out! :-)

Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> .. </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="logo"> .. </a>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="navigation">
<div class="founders2">
<div id="left_content">
<div class="news">Latest News &amp; Information</div>
<div id="right_content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    background:url(images/main/logo.png) top left no-repeat;
    width:391px;
    height:148px;
    font-size:0px;
    margin:-10px 0 0 0;
    float:left
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:url(images/main/bg.gif) repeat;
    #31
}

#header {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:147px;
    background:url(images/main/header_bg.gif) repeat-x;
}

#navigation {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:url(images/siteSlice_13.gif) repeat-x;   
}

#founders1 {}


#left_content {
    float:left;
    width:910px;
    height:100%;
}

#right_content {
    float:right;
    width:490px;
    height:100%;
}

#footer {
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:77px;
    background:url(images/siteSlice_96.gif) repeat-x;
}

/**
 * Needs to be aligned vertically.. no idea how.
 **/

.news {
    font-family:ubuntu;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000 12;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:15px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/main/news_header.gif) no-repeat;
    margin:100px;
}

.founders2 {
    background:url(images/main/founders_navbar.gif) no-repeat;
    width:265px;
    height:52px;
    margin:0 0 0 600px;
}
```

Anything not in the /main/ image folder hasn't been re-edited by myself yet, but is still a basic image that should act in the same way as when a new one replaces it.

Comment: Pasted your code into a fiddle so I could play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/QGh5t/ - w/out any images it's kind of hard to see what it's doing, but I did notice your div tags don't really match up. The first thing you should probably do is make sure every <div> has a matching </div> and that they're nested properly - try indenting so you can see how they're nested... (Fixing this should resolve issue #3 - all of your content, and your footer is inside the founders2 div)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had forgot that the tutorial had told me to extend the div downwards, but I had forgot that I had removed what was originally there, thus meaning I needed to add the tags back! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Centered Page Content**

One way you could center the body of a fixed width page layout with could be done with Auto Margins, as I will show in the following example

This is a basic example with only a div element which will be our website container.
You can apply a fixed with either to the container or to the body, and apply the automatic margins to the container itself...

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Website</title>
<link href="center.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!---
    other header and meta stuff ...
--->

</head>

<body>
 <div id="box_content">
    <p>
     My Content Area.
    </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS for the above:
**CSS for Center Aligned Content using Centered Body**

In this CSS example for the above HTML code, we center our container (div) element by applying a fixed width to the **Body** element, and assigning **Auto** margins to the same element. The margins will expand evenly on both sides to preserve the fixed 800px with, thus centering the page:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


body{
    /*
        Applying a fixed width with automatic margins will center the page:
    */
    width: 800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    /*
        and whatever...
    */
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*
        Here we have a gray background so we can see the centered content area
    */
    background-color:#CCC;
}

/*
    Our content area will be white  so we can see it centered over the gray background. 
*/
#box_content{
    background-color:#FFF;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

However, you can also apply the fixed width to the container itself instead. 
The following example works with the above HTML code.

**CSS Example with centered div element**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


body{

    /*
        Here we have a gray background so we can see the centered content area
    */
    background-color:#CCC;
}

/*
    Our content area will be white  so we can see it centered over the gray background. 
*/
#box_content{
    /*
        Applying a fixed width with automatic margins will center the page, 
        will also work on the container itself:
    */
    width: 800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    /*
        and whatever...
    */
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Both of the above CSS examples look exactly the same. (Should look the same on all the modern web browsers ).

There are various other ways to center using CSS ( including setting Position to 50% with a -400 margine, but this breaks on some renderers ).

The approach I have demonstrated is simply my simple but my preferred approach to centered fixed width layouts.

Also, I removed the 100% width values on your nested elements that dont need them ( div elements will default to 100% width anyhow )

100% Height will not work, a div element will not expand vertically to its container, unless you use absolute positioning ( but will expand to page size, and not the parent container size ). [DynamicDrive has examples on how to do this.](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/)

Also looking at your Source, I suggest changing the following:

```
font-family:ubuntu;
```

Because it is not a font family recognized by all operating systems, so visitors to your web page will most likely not see the same fonts *you* see on your own system. unless you use [ServerSide Fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

If you don't use a server side font, [it would be best to stick to common fonts and font families that (usually) exist on all major operating systems](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) if you want all users on all major operating systems to see the same font regardless of whichever web browser they use.

## 3 Slice Buttons

One again - there are more than one way to do this. One of the easier ways to do it would be to layer 3 divs and apply a slice to each layer. The following example is from a simple resizable button in one of my own template designs, a simple box-model button to say the least.

*Note: I think nesting div elements in a << a >> hyperlink is considered a bad practice? Although I do it anyhow ... I could be wrong.*

**HTML**

```
    <a href="contact.php" style="float:right">
        <div class="b_1"><div class="b_2"><div class="b_3">
        Contact
        </div></div></div>
    </a>
```

The CSS for the above button:

```
/*
    Contains the left slice of the button:
*/
.box_nav a          .b_1{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-image: url(ui/ui_19.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*
    Contains the Right slice of my button:
*/
.box_nav a          .b_2{
    background-image: url(ui/ui_23.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

/*
    COntains the tiled center slice of the button
*/
.box_nav a          .b_3{
    background-image: url(ui/ui_21.png);
    height: 43px;
    margin-right: 10px; /* This margin is the same width as the RIGHT slice */
    margin-left: 10px;  /* This margin is the same width as the LEFT  slice */
    line-height: 40px;  /* my way of centering text vertically in the button */
    text-align: center;
    /*
        prevents buttons with more than one word ( has spaces ) from breaking into two lines 
    */
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.box_nav a:hover    .b_1{
    background-image: url(ui/ui_24.png);
}
.box_nav a:hover    .b_2{
    background-image: url(ui/ui_28.png);
}
.box_nav a:hover    .b_3{
    background-image: url(ui/ui_26.png);
}
```

As seen above, this is a box model structure. The box_nav itself however requires "overflow:auto;" or "overflow:hidden;" however if height is not set explicitly.

The above button from my actual example looks like this:
[image: 3Slice Button]

## Final Section

As for your 3rd question, I don't actually understand what you are asking, and the html/css combination breaks in my browser when I copy your code. ( also I cant see it properly because I also don't have your images. I'm not sure what you were trying there, but i looks like your were trying a 3 column layout?

Your html for this section pretty much completely falls apart in my browser ( and also in dreamweaver )

## UPDATE:

As requested by you, here are two ways to do fluid layouts:

In this example, you can use the same automargins with a fluid width like this ( simply modify the fixed 800PX width to a fluid width, such as **80%**

```
width: 80%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

If you want *fixed margins with a fluid layout*, you can simply set margins, but do not set a width:

```
width: auto;
margin-left:100px;
margin-right:100px;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It has really helped me in understanding CSS - as well as your helpful tips that you took your time out to tell me. I really appreciate this, but was wondering if there was a way to make the body centered with a fluid layout?

I'm looking to make the header's image extend out all the way by repeating on it's X-axis, whereas the main content area will be in a fixed position as you have demonstrated.

Comment: I will update my answer with two fluid layout options.  EDIT: Updated my post.

Comment: Also, ( im not sure what your header image looks like ) but: 

 - IF it is a tiled image: auto width with tiling image and manual height. 

 - If it is a image (img) element:  Width 100% ( but do not set height ). An image via the IMG element will maintain aspect shape if you only set width but not height.

Comment: The image is tiled, yes.